# Intel store instructions on delibrately overlapping memory regions

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx

I have to store the lower 3 doubles in YMM register into an unaligned double array of size 3 (that is, cannot write the 4th element). But being a bit naughty, I'm wondering if the AVX intrinsic `_mm256_storeu2_m128d` can do the trick. I had

```
reg = _mm256_permute4x64_pd(reg, 0b10010100); // [0 1 1 2]
_mm256_storeu2_m128d(vec, vec + 1, reg);
```

and compiling by clang gives

```
vmovupd xmmword ptr [rsi + 8], xmm1 # reg in ymm1 after perm
vextractf128    xmmword ptr [rsi], ymm0, 1
```

If `storeu2` had semantics like `memcpy` then it most definitely triggers undefined behavior. But with the generated instructions, would this be free of race conditions (or other potential problems)?

*Other ways to store YMM into size 3 arrays are welcomed as well.*

Comment: It might still be undefined behaviour if it sometimes generates different instructions.

Comment: @user253751 That's true, but in that case I can change my intrinsics to `_mm_storeu_pd` and `extractf128_pd` or even use inline asm.

Comment: What about `_mm256_maskstore_pd`?

Comment: @chtz, that is the most logical solution I'd say, but if I'm reading the Agner's manual right, it's 4 uops and has a 14 cycle latency on Skylake. So it seems pretty slow for some reason.

Comment: [uops.info](https://uops.info/html-instr/VMASKMOVPD_M256_YMM_YMM.html) says it is 3 uops (and up to 14c latency) on Skylake. I doubt you can do much better (without writing outside your 3-sized array). If latency is an issue, you should reconsider your algorithm.

Comment: @chtz: oh interesting, yet another case of a mistake in Agner's hand-edited spreadsheets, it seems :/  Yeah, that would make `vmaskmov` worth using.  And it's only 1 store, so if you're close to bottlenecking on store uop throughput it's only 1 uop each of store-address and store-data, not 2, even on Haswell.  (Where Agner lists it as 2c throughput.  I'm curious if that's real, and if so what he measured differently from uops.info).  Anyway, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a formal spec for Intel's intrinsics, AFAIK, other than what Intel has published as documentation.  e.g. their intrinsics guide.  Also examples from their whitepapers and so on; e.g. examples that need to work are one way GCC/clang know they have to define `__m128` with `__attribute__((may_alias))`.

It's all within one thread, fully synchronous, so definitely no "race condition".  In your case it doesn't even matter which order the stores happen in (assuming they don't overlap with the `__m256d reg` object itself!  That would be the equivalent of an overlapping memcpy problem.)  What you're doing might be like two [indeterminately sequenced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) memcpy to overlapping destinations: they definitely happen in one order or the other, and the compiler could pick either.

The observable difference for order of stores is performance: if you want to do a SIMD reload very soon after, then store forwarding will work better if the 16-byte reload takes its data from one 16-byte store, not the overlap of two stores.

In general overlapping stores are fine for performance, though; the store buffer will absorb them.  It means one of them is unaligned, though, and crossing a cache-line boundary would be more expensive.

---

**However, that's all moot: [Intel's intrinsics guide does list an "operation" section for that compound intrinsic](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,FMA,Other&expand=1879,5659&text=_mm256_storeu2_m128d)**:

> Operation
>
> ```
> MEM[loaddr+127:loaddr] := a[127:0]
> MEM[hiaddr+127:hiaddr] := a[255:128]
> ```

So it's strictly defined as low address store first (the second arg; I think you got this backwards).

---

#### And all of that is also moot because there's a more efficient way

Your way costs 1 lane-crossing shuffle + vmovups + `vextractf128 [mem], ymm, 1`.  Depending on how it compiles, neither store can start until after the shuffle.  (Although it looks like clang might have avoided that problem).

On Intel CPUs, `vextractf128 [mem], ymm, imm` costs 2 uops for the front-end, *not* micro-fused into one.  (Also 2 uops on Zen for some reason.)

On AMD CPUs before Zen 2, lane-crossing shuffles are more than 1 uop, so `_mm256_permute4x64_pd` is more expensive than necessary.

**You just want to store the low lane of the input vector, and the low element of the high lane**.  The cheapest shuffle is `vextractf128 xmm, ymm, 1` - 1 uop / 1c latency on Zen (which splits YMM vectors into two 128-bit halves anyway).  It's as cheap as any other lane-crossing shuffle on Intel.

The asm you want the compiler to make is probably this, which only requires AVX1.  AVX2 doesn't have any useful instructions for this.

```
    vextractf128  xmm1, ymm0, 1            ; single uop everywhere
    vmovupd       [rdi], xmm0              ; single uop everywhere
    vmovsd        [rdi+2*8], xmm1          ; single uop everywhere
```

**So you want something like this, which should compile efficiently.**

```
    _mm_store_pd(vec, _mm256_castpd256_pd128(reg));  // low half
    __m128d hi = _mm256_extractf128_pd(reg, 1);
    _mm_store_sd(vec+2, hi);
    // or    vec[2] = _mm_cvtsd_f64(hi);
```

`vmovlps` (`_mm_storel_pi`) would also work, but with AVX VEX encoding it doesn't save any code size, and would require even more casting to keep compilers happy.

There's unfortunately no `vpextractq [mem], ymm`, only with an XMM source so that doesn't help.

---

#### Masked store:

As discussed in comments, yes you could do `vmaskmovps` but it's unfortunately not as efficient as we might like on all CPUs.  Until AVX512 makes masked loads/stores first-class citizens, it may be best to shuffle and do 2 stores.  Or pad your array / struct so you can at least temporarily step on later stuff.

Zen has 2-uop `vmaskmovpd ymm` loads, but *very* expensive `vmaskmovpd` stores (42 uops, 1 per 11 cycles for YMM).  Or Zen+ and Zen2 are 18 or 19 uops, 6 cycle throughput.  **If you care at all about Zen, avoid `vmaskmov`**.

On Intel Broadwell and earlier, `vmaskmov` stores are 4 uops according to [Agner's Fog's](https://agner.org/optimize/) testing, so that's 1 more fused-domain uop than we get from shuffle + movups + movsd.  But still, Haswell and later do manage 1/clock throughput so if that's a bottleneck then it beats the 2-cycle throughput of 2 stores.  SnB/IvB of course take 2 cycles for a 256-bit store, even without masking.

On Skylake, [`vmaskmov mem, ymm, ymm` is only 3 uops](https://uops.info/html-instr/VMASKMOVPD_M256_YMM_YMM.html) (Agner Fog lists 4, but his spreadsheets are hand-edited and have been wrong before.  I think it's safe to assume uops.info's automated testing is right.  And that makes sense; Skylake-client is basically the same core as Skylake-AVX512, just without actually enabling AVX512.  So they could implement `vmaskmovpd` by decoding it into test into a mask register (1 uop) + masked store (2 more uops without micro-fusion).

**So if you only care about Skylake and later, and can amortize the cost of loading a mask into a vector register (reusable for loads and stores), `vmaskmovpd` is actually pretty good.**  Same front-end cost but cheaper in the back-end: only 1 each store-address and store-data uops, instead of 2 separate stores.  **Note the 1/clock throughput on Haswell and later vs. the 2-cycle throughput for doing 2 separate stores.**

`vmaskmovpd` might even store-forward efficiently to a masked reload; I think Intel mentioned something about this in their optimization manual.